# How do I make behave smoke to try the last failed scenario first?

Tags: python, selenium, python-behave, smoke-testing

`py.test` has a wonderful feature called `--failed-first` which tells it to run the tests that failed last time before the others. This speeds up the execution process considerably.

I am looking for something similar for `behave smoke`. Is there way to implement this?

Comment: What do the docs for that tool tell you?

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything in the docs regarding a feature like this, that's why I asked.

Comment: I don't think there is. I'm also not sure how this would speed up the execution process as it'll still execute the same amount of tests?

Comment: @RemcoW I assume the OP means because if they fail again, you don't have to wait through the rest of the suite to find out.